# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? or tel=?' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here's my query:

```
select *
from reg
where indexno=?
or tel=?
```

And here's my code:

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://url","unam","pass");
String query = "select * from reg where indexno= ? or tel=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, in.getText());
ps.setString(2, tl.getText());
Statement st =  con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: What is the type of column `indexno`? Also, more than 20 years ago it stopped being necessary for you to execute `Class.forName()`

Comment: integer data type column

Comment: You are setting its value to a string. Try `ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(in.getText()))`

Comment: no i am getting the same error again

Comment: it ask to check this line java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and tel=?' at line 1

Comment: Show table create statement (relevant columns only).

Comment: create table reg(indexno int primary key not null, fname varchar(255) not null, lname varchar(255) not null, age int not null, tel int not null );

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace to give us a clue, where the error actually happens.

Comment: Statement st =  con.createStatement(); its happened on here

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a closer look at what your code is doing.

Connecting to the database:

```java
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://url","unam","pass");
```

Creating the SQL query:

```java
String query = "select * from reg where indexno= ? or tel=?"`;
```

Creating a prepared statement:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
```

Setting some bind parameter values:

```java
ps.setString(1, in.getText());
ps.setString(2, tl.getText());
```

Creating a whole new non-prepared statement (wait, what? Why are we not using the prepared statement we spent some time creating?):

```java
Statement st =  con.createStatement();
```

Using the new non-prepared statement to execute the SQL query.

```java
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

As a result of the last two lines, your SQL query is sent straight to the MySQL database. MySQL doesn't understand what the `?` marks are for, and hence complains with a syntax error about them.

When handling prepared statements, JDBC drivers will either replace the `?` marks with the database's own syntax for bind parameters (unless the database supports `?` marks directly, but not all databases do), or put the values directly in the SQL string after suitable escaping of any characters, before they send the SQL to the database. `Statement`s don't support bind parameters, and will just send the SQL string they are given straight to the database.

Your code creates a `PreparedStatement` and sets two bind parameter values. It seems a shame not to actually use your prepared statement once you've created it. You can get the result set you want out of it by calling `ps.executeQuery()`.  There is no need for the separate `Statement` you created by calling `connection.createStatement()`.

The fix therefore is to remove the last two lines of the code in your question and add the following line in place of them:

```java
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: _"The `?` marks are part of the JDBC standard, they are not understood by databases."_, some database systems actually do understand the question marks natively (when used appropriately with prepared statements), they are even specified in ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016 (the SQL standard).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: thanks, I've no removed any comment about 'the JDBC standard'. Off the top of my head I can't think of a database that does support `?` marks directly (certainly not one I use regularly), but that of course doesn't mean that there isn't one.

Comment: Some database that support `?` natively: Firebird, Db2, MySQL (though MySQL Connector/J *defaults* to using inlining instead of using server-side prepared statements), MariaDB (probably same limitation as MySQL), SQLite, possibly SQL Server (but that might be limited to client API translation and `EXECUTE`)